# Yahoo table centering alignment

Tags: css, html-email, yahoo

```
<body bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="background:#f6f6f6; border:0; color:#9e9e9e; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="table-layout: fixed; margin: 0 auto; background:#f6f6f6;">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" valign="top">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" border="0" align="center" width="600" class="fullWidth">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="spacer.gif" width="100%" height="30" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- More tables with content -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I've done a lot of testing on this and research. I believe that I am doing this correctly however when I go to test it expecting the table to be centered in yahoo it isn't!

The fix is supposed to be putting table-layout: fixed; on the outer table with 100% width on.

which I've done.

So can anyone spot what I've done wrong here to not make this work?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should fix it. Your email code just needs a few more `CSS` resets.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
            table {
                border-spacing: 0 !important;
                border-collapse: collapse !important;
                table-layout: fixed !important;
                margin: 0 auto !important;
            }
            table table table {
                table-layout: auto; 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="background:#f6f6f6; border:0; color:#9e9e9e; margin:0; padding:0;">
        <center style="width: 100%; background: #f6f6f6;">

            <!-- Your Email Code Begins Here -->
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="table-layout: fixed; margin: 0 auto; background:#f6f6f6;">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%" valign="top">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f6f6f6" border="0" align="center" width="600" class="fullWidth">
                            <tr>
                                <td><img src="spacer.gif" width="100%" height="30" alt="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- More tables with content -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Your Email Code Ends Here -->

        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The above will work, or you can just add align="center" to the first <td> tag, which wraps the content table. The essential bit is that Yahoo ignores the align parameter on tables, it only pays attention to what's in <td> tags.